# star pattern using recursive func in c

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to develop a C code that generates * a pattern by given input. First it must print star descending by 2 and after ascending by 2. like:

**input**

```
enter number: 8
```

**output**

```
********
******
****
**
****
******
********
```

here is what i did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printpattern(int n){
    if(n==0)return 0;
    printf("*");
    printpattern(n-1);
}

int pattern(int n){
    if(n==0)return 0;
    puts("\n");
    printpattern(n);
    pattern(n-2);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    puts("number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n%2==1){
        puts("must be even");
        main();
    }
    pattern(n);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks..

Comment: Your code was formatted badly and hence unreadable. You should tell us what output you are getting and what the problem is (not just "complete my program for me").  You obviously need a loop that counts from n to down to 1 or 2, print the minimum and then back up to to n again.  You can also do it recursively instead of a loop(s) if you want.

Comment: Never call `main` from your program.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` to enter a parameter.  `main` takes 2 arguments, and you should pass the parameter there (ie, as an argument when you start the program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the function main recursively will result in executing these statements in each invocation of main

```
puts("number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
```

So it is not a good idea to call main recursively.

I would write the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_pattern( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        putchar( '*' );
        print_pattern( n - 1 );
    }
}

void pattern( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        print_pattern( n );
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        if ( n > 2 )
        {
            pattern( n - 2 );
            print_pattern( n );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }
}
    
int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        pattern( n );
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

********
******
****
**
****
******
********

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

*******
*****
***
*
***
*****
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

******
****
**
****
******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

*****
***
*
***
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

****
**
****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

***
*
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

**

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Of course you can call the function only for even numbers though the function is more general and can be called for any non-negative number.

The function itself should not depend on whether an even or odd number was passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the question states you must use recursion, it makes a lot more sense to use recursion this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void printstars(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void printpattern(int n)
{
    printstars(n);
    if (n > 4) {
        printpattern(n - 2);
    } else {
        printstars(2);
    }
    printstars(n);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    puts("number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n & 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "must be even\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printpattern(n);
    return 0;
}
```